# How can I keep from retyping the same line of code over and over?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, code-snippets

I want to understand if code snippets are what I am looking for here.
I wind up writing the same line of code over and over during a refactoring.
Is there anyway I can create a shortcut that will spit out a line of code that I need?

Comment: As I understand from 'spit out', you are looking for certain lines of code to be re-written in certain another form, which u want to do repetitively??

Comment: Please say why the paste command is not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another easier option is to drag the code blocks that you re-use frequently onto the [general tab of your toolbox](http://dotnetslackers.com/Visual_Studio/re-136816_Visual_Studio_Tooltips_unplugged_Drag_and_Drop_code_artifacts_to_Toolbox_General_Tab.aspx) area. You could even organize them with their own tab name and all.

[alt text http://blogs.telerik.com/Libraries/MetaBlog/WindowsLiveWriter-VisualStudioTooltipsunpluggedDragandDro_EF10-generalTabDragged.sflb](http://blogs.telerik.com/Libraries/MetaBlog/WindowsLiveWriter-VisualStudioTooltipsunpluggedDragandDro_EF10-generalTabDragged.sflb)

Comment: This is fine if the code is always the same, unless I am wrong.  A code snippet allows you to define where the block of code may differ and flag them

Comment: A code snippet is always the best option. However this is a quick one-off solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you repeating the same line of code over and over on many different days?

Or are you encountering a situation where you have the same line to write many times as a part of a single task, but today's line of code will be different to tomorrows?

If you have the same line/block of code that you use often, a snippet is a good way to capture that in a reusable form (better, IMHO, than copy/paste because you can parameterise them).

However, if you're just looking for a quick way to repeat the same line that's come up now, check out Visual Studio's ability to record keystrokes.

Try this:

- Put your cursor on a blank line inside a C# method.
- Select `Tools|Macros|Record Temporary Macro` (often this is `Control-Shift-R`)
- Type "example();" and press return
- Select `Tools|Macros|Stop Recording`

You've just created a temporary macro that you can play back at any time - usually the keystroke for this is `Control-Shift-P`.

The key to this technique is that the macro records everything you do - with some practise, you can record edits to a line of code and repeat those edits on other lines.

I've used this in the past to create repetative code blocks - like assigning sets of properties from one object to another.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the code snippet, it would almost always be arguable that this line of code belongs in a util method, rather than copypasta.. But otherwise, yeah - a snippet is probably the best place.

Answer (score 0):

Code Snippets sound like the right approach, although you could investigate Macros inside Visual Studio, which can be very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of a code snippet over adding it to the toolbox is that you can define the parts of the code that you want to change.  I wrote a code snippet that generated something like the following code:

```
public class *className*Collection : List<*className*>
```

Where I only typed className once and it was automatically filled into the other parts.